# problem - when playing a sound the animation freeze\slowing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

when playing a sound the animation freeze\slowing  problem.

sound size 20kb mp3.

animation size 5kb png.

also happens in other animation functions.

basically whenever i play a sound the animation slowing down or pauses, what to do ???

code:

```
- (void) startAnimation { 

 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
 CGPoint destination = CGPointMake(152,20);
 pink.center = destination;
 [UIView commitAnimations];
 [soundPink play];    
}


- (void) initSoundResources {

 soundPink = [[APlayer alloc] initWithFile:@"ballShuffle" type:@"mp3"];
 soundPink = 0.4;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following hack:

```
[soundPink performSelector:@selector(play) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.001];
```

Comment: AVAudioPlayer is already asynchronous, this may not help, I've found that most of the audio pauses before playing are during the prepareToPlay stage which you can call manually.

Comment: but the animation pauses not the audio.

i post my init function (maybe something is wrong there)

Answer (score 0):

How large is the sound file? It's possible you're trying to load too large a sound into memory, which is slowing things down. Remember, the iPhone is not a desktop computer, so you have to consider the size of media files more carefully.

Comment: the biggest one is 400kb, is that too big?

Answer (score 0):

The answer may be to add a prepareToPlay can (which the play does explicitly) before the animation block so there is no stutter.

```
- (void) startAnimation {   
    [soundPink prepareToPlay];           
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
    CGPoint destination = CGPointMake(152,20);
    pink.center = destination;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [soundPink play];           
}
```